# Sort each column independently

Tags: sorting, command-line, multiple-columns

```
cat sanger.* | tr '\-ACGT' '01234' | sed -e 's/\([[:digit:]]\)/\1 /g' 

1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0  
0 2 2 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2   
0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0   
0 0 0 4 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0
```

This is my current output, now I want to sort each column independently, so all the numbers are on the same line.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sorting, here, but extracting the non-0 digits.

Here is an awk filter that "updates" each fields with the only (actually, the latest) non-"0" content it sees :

```
# short version
awk '/./ {  if ( NF > maxNF )  {  maxNF=NF }
            for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {  if ( $i!="0" ) { result[i]=$i } } 
         }
     END {  for(i=1;i<=maxNF;i++) { printf "%s ",result[i] } }
     '

# expanded version (ie, the same as above, with different indentation to mhelp reading)
awk '/./ {  if ( NF > maxNF )  
              {  maxNF=NF }
            for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
              {  if ( $i!="0" )
                   { result[i]=$i } 
              } 
         }
     END {  for(i=1;i<=maxNF;i++) 
              { printf "%s ",result[i] 
              } 
         }
    '
```

so if I paste your posted result into that filter:

```
echo "
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0  
0 2 2 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2   
0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0   
0 0 0 4 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 
" | awk '/./ {  if ( NF > maxNF )  {  maxNF=NF }
                for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {  if ( $i!="0" ) { result[i]=$i } } 
             }
         END {  for(i=1;i<=maxNF;i++) { printf "%s ",result[i] } }
        '
```

it outputs:

```
1 2 2 4 4 1 3 2 2 2 2 3 2 4 3 4 1 3 2 2 2 1 2 1 3 4 1 1 1 1 2
```

(note: with an extra " " at the end, here...)

A note of warning however: very OLD version of the original awk (and maybe some nawk) are limited to 99 fields... (Rarely encountered nowadays. And if you use GNU's version, you will be fine)

Comment: this is a really good answer but can it also be done with sed or sort because we haven't learned how to use awk, so we may not use this during exams.